# Databricks External Table

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have data stored on ADLS Gen2 and have 2 workspaces.

1. Primary ETL Workspace(**Workspace A**): Prepares data from sources and stores on ADLS (mounted to Databricks with SP as **Storage Blob Data Contributor** )
2. Sandbox Workspace(**Workspace B**) : Utilizes data from ADLS(read only) (mounted to Databricks with SP as **Storage Blob Data Reader**). Workspace B should always be able to READ only ADLS

```
ADLS/
 |-- curated/
 |   |-- google
 |      |-- table1
 |      |-- table2
 |   |-- data.com
 |      |-- table1
 |      |-- table2
```

Writing to the above location has no issues since we use Workspace A.
I see issue when layering External database/tables within Workspace B

Steps:

1. The following works

```
create database if not exists google_db comment 'Database for Google' location 'dbfs:/mnt/google'
```

2. The following **Fails**

```
create external table google_db .test USING DELTA location 'dbfs:/mnt/google/table1'
```

Message:

```
Error in SQL statement: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, PUT, https://XASASASAS.dfs.core.windows.net/google/table1/_delta_log?resource=directory&timeout=90, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:76142564-801f-000f-29cf-e6a826000000 Time:2021-12-01T16:21:33.3117578Z"

com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, PUT, https://XASASASAS.dfs.core.windows.net/google/table1/_delta_log?resource=directory&timeout=90, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:76142564-801f-000f-29cf-e6a826000000 Time:2021-12-01T16:21:33.3117578Z"
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:237)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.createPath(AbfsClient.java:311)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.createDirectory(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:632)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.mkdirs(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:481)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.$anonfun$mkdirs$3(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:748)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.s3a.S3AExceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:66)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.$anonfun$mkdirs$2(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:746)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.$anonfun$withUserContextRecorded$2(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:941)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withUserContextRecorded(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:914)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.$anonfun$mkdirs$1(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:745)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.recordOperation(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.mkdirs(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:745)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.mkdirs(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1881)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:110)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.$anonfun$run$2(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:132)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:56)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:70)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:402)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:381)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordOperation(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:52)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:113)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:97)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.recordDeltaOperation(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:52)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.commands.CreateDeltaTableCommand.run(CreateDeltaTableCommand.scala:108)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaCatalog.com$databricks$sql$transaction$tahoe$catalog$DeltaCatalog$$createDeltaTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:162)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.catalog.DeltaCatalog$StagedDeltaTableV2.commitStagedChanges(DeltaCatalog.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.$anonfun$writeToTable$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:515)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1677)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.writeToTable$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicCreateTableAsSelectExec.writeToTable(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AtomicCreateTableAsSelectExec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$logicalPlan$1(Dataset.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3802)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:687)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.$anonfun$executeSql$1(SQLDriverLocal.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:37)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:544)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:521)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:544)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:521)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, if database/tables created with the following way, goes through

1. Create database without location

```
create database if not exists google_db comment 'Database for Google'
```

2. This **Works**

```
create table google_db.test USING DELTA location 'dbfs:/mnt/google/table1'
```

Not sure why Delta/Databricks is trying to write to the location when external database is defined.

The issue with the above is that users can still create additional tables under "google_db" since it is an internal database.User requirements state that data should be immutable (it is since users cannot updated/write to existing tables, but they are able to add tables to the database)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any info on this